# How to have row number in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I need to have counter in that. I mean, I need to have a column that shows the rows number in sort. For example:

```
|Num|Name |
-----------
| 1 |Alex |
| 2 |Alice|
| 3 |Cat  |
```

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? The StackOverflow community would generally expect a question to show some research effort: please post the code you've already tried.

Comment: OK, just wait for seconds.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2eead3e3-5cc2-40f7-a91c-8f7942d5329c/how-to-display-row-numbers-in-gridviewurgently-required?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following code in a label:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```